# How to solve "Can't separate key from value" in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

After upgrading my docker desktop, I get an error when running `docker-compose up`. My usual setup consists of microservices controlled with the `docker-compose` command. When I run `docker-compose up`, all the containers are started. After updating my docker desktop, I get:

```sh
Can't separate key from value
```

while running `docker-compose up`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check for the version number of docker and if its 3.4+ then the docker compose v2 is enabled by default. To disable it, go to > docker desktop > preferences > experimental features > un-check "use Docker Compose V2" option. This is a move by docker hub to incorporate docker-compose as `docker compose` and may cause problems to your usual workflow. Enjoy :)

Comment: This "fixed" the issue but I'm curious if this is documented somewhere and also exactly what changes need to be made in order to get docker compose files working with docker compose v2. I lost an entire day on this a few weeks ago.

Comment: more information here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/ . Please feel free to edit / append the answers with more info as required :)

Answer (score 6):

Just in case if anyone else (like me) run into this issue:

Check the local (to docker-compose.yaml) `.env` file, is there a VARIABLE without mapping? If so... remove it or give it a value...

Answer (score 1):

More specifically maybe:

```
MY_VAR=  // works fine
MY_VAR2  // fails
; MY VAR // also fails
; MY_VAR=  // works, but fails later with an actually useful msg
```